# Changing dynamically the src path iframe for Youtube with jquery for Foundation 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, modal-dialog

I don't understand why this is not working. I try to send some id of a image when i click on them to a modal. With this id, I change the path of the src of the iframe.
It's work for the first click but after this, it's always the same id if i click on other images

live exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/gRtrX/39/

Images are generate dynamically so i can't use simple id to call her. I just know the src and the id

But the attr doesn't work.

```
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7ZAzp9UtxXo/default.jpg" id="7ZAzp9UtxXo">
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hn5gEo_BBOY/default.jpg" id="hn5gEo_BBOY">
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DhaGjkTVfIg/default.jpg" id="DhaGjkTVfIg">
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gZ_qt7Oo3tE/default.jpg" id="gZ_qt7Oo3tE">
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OUEaFKWUiVI/default.jpg" id="OUEaFKWUiVI">
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/h5cDiLHs2JM/default.jpg" id="h5cDiLHs2JM">


    <div id="modal-video" class="reveal-modal small" data-reveal>


          <div class="flex-video">
            <iframe width="420" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
        <!-- end lecteur controles -->
        <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>

</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">

          $(document).ready(function() {
            $('img').click(function() {
                console.log(this.id);
                $(".flex-video > iframe").attr("src", "//www.youtube.com/embed/"+this.id);
                $('#modal-video').foundation('reveal', 'open');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

EDIT : maybe it's a foundation problem, don't understand.

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/P7FM7/

Comment: well see mine jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gRtrX/39/ if you click on image the good thumbnails appears 2s and the old thumbnails appears. if you play the video it's always the same.

Comment: seems like foundation is caching it somehow...might look for a calllback for the open event and set src in that callback